# MVC3 web app running on IIS6 server images not showing up per "/content/themes/base/images" path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I recently published my MVC3 app to an IIS6.0 server and I have the following image reference in a .js script (see code block below) but the images are not showing up.  I know that @Url.Content() works but I can't use that in a .js script.

Q1: What is the proper path to reference for images (or whatever contents)?  Thx!

```
src: '/content/themes/base/images/down.gif'
```

Q2: The following controller/action isn't firing in my ajax/jquery method (I'm sure it's related) but same issue with path:

```
        $.ajax(
            { url: '/Controller/MyMethod',   // Not firing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place: `@Url.Content("~/Content/Image ...")` instead of url only

Answer (score 1):

Paths off the root of your web directory should be prefaced by '~/' like so:

```
src: '~/content/themes/base/images/down.gif'
```

This tells the server that the path is relative to the root.

Comment: hmm also. This is how I do it all the time.  Fortunately you are incorrect about not being able to use @Url.Action in your script.  As long as the script is on your view page and not a separate file you can say:  var url='@Url.Content("/controller/action")';

Comment: Thanks for the replies Joshua!  Yeah, I was able to get the '@Url.Action(..)' working but not sure what is going on with the relative path stuff.

Comment: No problem!  Don't forget to up-vote please!  Couldn't say why the relative paths aren't working, haven't encountered the issue before, maybe it's something funny about your deployment procedure, like maybe t's wrapping everything in another folder or something.